# My Mac account is completely blocked

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mac, accounts

I recently had some problem with my account that I use on a regular basis.

After logging in, my Mac blocks completely showing the spinning color wheel everywhere I click to open something. Finally I need to restart my mac, because I'm not able to do anything. Now, the strange thing is that this does not happen when I log in into another account on my mac, then is everything working fine.

Anyone that knows how an issue like this?

My mac is on Mac OS X Mavericks and is a Macbook Pro Mid-2010.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to login in without starting login items and opening finder windows. You can do this by holding down the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key after you type your username and password at the login screen.

This will probably only solve simple problems with your login. More details are available here: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14215

Comment: Holding SHIFT when logging in did nothing for me...

Answer (score 0):

Here are some choices I suggest:

- One is to move all the stuff from the broken account to the working one, then delete the broken account. Make the new one account the administrator account.
- The second option is to repair the broken account.

  1. Restart Computer, and before you hear the chime, hold down the Command and R keys.
  2. You’ll be at the Repair Utilities screen. Click the Utilities item in the Menu Bar, then click Terminal.
  3. In the Terminal window, type `resetpassword` and hit Return.
  4. The password reset utility window launches, but you’re **not going to reset the password**. Instead, click on icon for your Mac’s hard drive at the top. From the dropdown below it, select the user account where you’re having issues.
  5. At the bottom of the window, you’ll see an area labeled Reset Home Directory Permissions and ACLs. Click the Reset button there.

The reset process takes just a couple of minutes. When it’s done, exit the programs you’ve opened and restart your Mac.

[Source](http://blog.chron.com/techblog/2011/09/want-to-really-repair-permissions-on-your-mac-try-this/)

**UPDATE:** since you want to try to repair that account and based on you console log:

Analyzing your log it shows:

- SMC errors, so reset your SMC
- Disk I/O errors (not so good news) try to repair it in Terminal with `/sbin/fsck -fy`
- Recommend to disable all and any Sharing settings (in System Preferences)

Postscriptum:

Your used profile so massively messed up, I do not know what was done to it, but I would create a new profile and just copy files over.

Comment: I tried repairing it, but this did not help me. It is no different than before. And I really want to avoid doing your first choice, maybe you have another option in mind?

Comment: yes, for that show me your console log about 30 lines

Comment: My log is pasted [here](http://pastebin.com/Ge6MVsL7). It is between two boots in which I logged into my account that freezes my mac.